# How to create project wise documentation in single Docusaurus application

Tags: docusaurus

I have more than a single project and I want to create documentation for each project.
APIs listed for one project should not be visible in another project.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can just do this using multiple sidebars. When you display a page on sidebar A, you won't see sidebar B nor any of the pages listed in it, and vice versa.

In fact this is the case on the Docusaurus website where the "Docs" documentation is kept separate from the "API" documentation. Links to both appear in the header but if you remove these links, you can't get to an API page from the Docs documentation, and vice versa.

This is explained here: https://docusaurus.io/docs/sidebar/multiple-sidebars

They show this example:

```
sidebars.js
export default {
  tutorialSidebar: {
    'Category A': ['doc1', 'doc2'],
  },
  apiSidebar: ['doc3', 'doc4'],
};
```

When browsing doc1 or doc2, the tutorialSidebar will be displayed; when browsing doc3 or doc4, the apiSidebar will be displayed.

I just finished the same set-up at work where we want a user guide that displays when someone clicks on the "help" icon from our UI, and a more detailed integration/configuration guide that's only displayed for certain users.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).